# What movie is this? Alien living as humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, soft-sci-fi

I can't remember the name of this movie, but is old, from the 1960's or 70's. It was about a community hidden out in the boonies. Maybe farmers. A couple visits this community, probably to study them. These people are taught that they can not raise their feet, thus when they walk, they drag their feet. There is one scene where some kids are floating; that may be what happens when they do not drag their feet. They are actually aliens that were stranded on Earth, living as humans for a couple / several generations. Offspring where the ones not allowed to walk normal but instead drag their feet.

The outsider Female might have been a teacher or a doctor.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59700/can-anyone-identify-a-story-about-people-who-could-fly (question about original story)

Comment: OMGosh! I have been searching for the name of this movie for years. I always had an odd fascination with this movie. Its storyline just seemed to have stuck with me as a child so many decades ago. Thank you fof finally posting and for giving me another opportunity to see it once again.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're describing [The People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People_(1972_film)) (1972) starring William Shatner and Kim Darby.

It was based on Zenna Henderson's "Pottage", one of the stories found in her anthology "[The Pilgrimage](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/491889.Pilgrimage)"

- Aliens have crash-landed on the Earth.
- They live in remote parts of the world.
- Their offspring have ESP and levitating powers and are taught to drag their feet along the ground to disguise their gift.
- The protagonist is a teacher.

Comment: I hadn't realized that anyone had ever made a People movie. Hunh. Thanks for that. I mean, I know it stars the Shat, but is it actually any good?

Comment: @Brokylnite - The link is the full movie so you can make your own judgement but no, it's not a good film.

Comment: Bad movie.  No cookie.

Comment: @DoscoJones - I've seen worse. Go watch [Starcrash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LOpi6TsW4o).

Comment: @Valorum: found in her collection, you mean, not her anthology. an anthology means a book of works by different author.

Comment: @RiaByss - The word anthology can mean either a body of works by a singular author or a selection of works by various authors.

Comment: @Valorum: technically, yes, but it bothers me almost as much as "fiction novel".

Comment: @RiaByss - I can only imagine your fury when you find out that 'literally' doesn't mean what you think it means either. You will be [literally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally) incandescent with rage.

Comment: @Valorum:  misuse of literally does bother me. I don't consider it trivial (unlike anthology versus collection or "fiction novel".) the majority of people think using an internal monologue. those who don't have an internal monologue, at least, speak/write with others. if you can't tell the difference between "figurative" and "literal", you have a tool missing in your cognitive toolbox.

Comment: @RiaByss - Whenever anyone tells me that they're upset about 'literally' being misused, I like to point out to them that the meaning they think is correct (e.g. literally = actually) is also a neologism from the 1600s. Prior to that it just meant "written down" (as opposed to 'orally'). I can only imagine people from the early 1700s getting angry because people are using 'literally' wrong.

Comment: @Valorum: that does not make my point any less valid.

Comment: @RiaByss - Dictionary purists who want all the words pinned to the page like butterflies are always going to be disappointed. A word isn't being "misused" if that's how people use it.

Comment: @Valorum: it does not have to do with the misuse of the word. it has to do with the *disuse* of the idea of a distinction between literal and figurative speech. that matters.