# YA novel about sister is alien with two hearts and assassins come

Tags: story-identification, novel

Plot of novel: sister is actually some alien planet's royalty but due to a coup d'etat she is surgically changed into a human and sent to live on earth in disguise. Unfortunately they get the wrong planet and gave her two hearts. An accident causes this to be revealed and now assassins are after her.

Aliens were beings of lights and they used water sprinklers as a weapon in one of the fights.

Comment: That rings a bell. Does it involve a New York cop who turns out to be a bodyguard who has also been transferred to Earth but has had his memory wiped?

Comment: Can't remember enough to be able to say, I did remember some other snippets though - added onto post. There were (alien) bodyguards involved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the book is the novelization of a 1992 Australian TV movie called *The Distant Home*.  Does [this description at Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6481880-the-distant-home) match the book you remember?

> Sally and Jimmy are twins living with their parents in the most boring suburban street in the world but on their 12th birthday an accident and subsequent medical treatment reveal that Sally is an alien. Her twin brother Jimmy is human but she is not. For a thousand years a space war has been raging between a Galactic Empire and Ursoid invaders and Sally, an Imperial princess, was implanted in the womb of a human mother in order to hide her from her Ursoid enemies. The night the twins were born, an old lady named Mrs Webster moved into the house next door and ever since she has given the twins cookies, milk and lessons in military strategy. Now Sally’s secret is out, her Ursoid enemies are coming for her and the twins and Mrs Webster, now revealed as an undercover Master Sergeant in the Imperial Marines, tasked to be Sally’ bodyguard, have to keep her alive until help arrives from the Galactic Empire.